# OpenStreetMapのマップを、mapnik + python + postgis で表示しようとしているが表示されない

Tags: python, postgresql, openstreetmap, mapnik

以下のツールを利用して、 OpenStreetMap の地図を表示しようとしています。

- postgresql --with-protobuf-c
- postgis
- mapnik --with-postgres
- osm2pgsql

`brew` コマンドでそれぞれインストールを行い、 シンプルな世界地図は表示されるようになりました。([world_map_and_styles.py](http://mapnik-utils.googlecode.com/svn/example_code/hello_world/pure_python/world_map_and_styles.py))

目的としては、日本周辺の地図を表示したいため、[日本周辺の地図データ](http://download.geofabrik.de/asia/japan.html)をダウンロードし、以下のコマンドを利用し、 DB を作成しました。

```
osm2pgsql -d gis japan-latest.osm.pbf --style openstreetmap-carto.style
```

(実際は、上記コマンドの前に、`osm2pgsql -d gis japan-latest.osm.pbf` のみを実行済みでした。)

その後、サンプルを改造した以下のコード(Python)を実行しているのですが、画像全体に、海部分のみが表示され、地形部分が全く表示されません。

ぜひ、解決のためのご助言を頂きたいです。  
よろしくお願いします。

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

from mapnik import *
import mapnik
import math


m = Map(600,300,'+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84')
m.background = Color('steelblue')
m.zoom_to_box( mapnik.Envelope(128.0,26.0,136.0,48.0) );
m.aspect_fix_mode = aspect_fix_mode.ADJUST_BBOX_HEIGHT


poly = PolygonSymbolizer(Color('lavender'))
line = LineSymbolizer(Color('slategray'),.3)
s,r = Style(),Rule()
r.symbols.extend([poly,line])
s.rules.append(r)
m.append_style('My Style',s)

# Layer
lyr = Layer('Geometry from PostGIS')
db_params = dict(
    #host='',
    #user='',
    #password ='',
    dbname='gis',
    table='planet_osm_polygon'
)
lyr.datasource = PostGIS(**db_params)

lyr.srs = '+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84'
lyr.styles.append('My Style')
m.layers.append(lyr)

render_to_file(m, 'map/hello_world_in_pure_python.png')
```

Comment: 手元での再現に必要だった引数などの情報を追加しました

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBの空間参照系と一致させるため、レイヤーに指定する`srs` (spatial reference system) をosm2pgsqlがデフォルトで使う空間参照系にする必要があります:

```
merc = mapnik.Projection('+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m  +nadgrids=@null +no_defs +over')
lyr.srs = merc.params()
```

関連ドキュメント: ["Getting Started in Python - Creating a Layer"](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/GettingStartedInPython#create-a-layer)

出力結果:

[image: レンダリング結果]

なお、`Map`に設定する`srs`は、レンダリング時に利用する空間参照系になります。

osm2pgsqlがデフォルトで使う空間参照系は、ヘルプで調べることができ、

```
$ osm2pgsql --help  | grep default
   ...
   -m|--merc        Store data in proper spherical mercator (default).
```

[manページ](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/blob/master/docs/osm2pgsql.1#L251)に必要なパラメータの詳細が書かれています。

```
Spherical Mercator  (\-m) SRS:900913 +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs +over
```

また、DBがどの空間参照系を直接調べることもできます:

```
$ psql gis
gis=# select Find_SRID('', 'planet_osm_polygon', 'way');
 find_srid
-----------
    900913
```

SRIDが分かったら、それをキーにして`Projection`に渡すための[PROJ.4](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/)形式のパラメータを調べます:

```
gis=# \x
gis=# select auth_name, proj4text from spatial_ref_sys where srid=900913;
-[ RECORD 1 ]---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
auth_name | spatialreferencing.org
proj4text | +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs
```

SRIDは空間参照系に割り振られているIDのことで、これを指定することで`Projection`に渡すパラメータを省略することもできます:

```
# /usr/local/share/proj/ にある定義ファイルが参照されます。
# 今回はgrepしてどのファイルに定義されているか探しました。
merc = mapnik.Projection('+init=other.extra:900913')
```